# Analyse an image and match to the closest color palette

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have a set number of color palettes (8), each with 5 colors. The goal is to process an image with canvas and determine which color palette is the closest match.

Atm the minute I am getting the average RGB value from the palette then, doing the same with the source image before converting it to LAB and using [CIE1976](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE76) to calculate the color difference. The closest match is the smallest distance.

This works to an extent, but many of the images I'm testing match two particular palettes. Is there a better way to calculate the most relevant palettes for an image?

So I've changed it to work with histograms. I'll put some of the code below but basically I'm:

- Creating a 3D RGB histogram from the selected image, splitting rgb values into one of 8 banks, (8*8*8) so 512.
- Flattening the histogram to create a single 512 array.
- Normalizing the values by dividing by the total pixels in the image.
- I do the same for the color palettes, creating a flat 512 histogram.
- Calculate the chi-squared distance between the two histogram to find the closest color palette.

With my color palettes only having 5 colors their histogram is quite empty. Would this be an issue when comparing histograms with chi-squared.

This is how I create the flat histogram for the images to be analysed.

```
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                imgWidth = this.width,
                imgHeight = this.height,
                totalPixels = imgWidth * imgHeight;

            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

            var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight).data;
            var x, y, z, histogram = new Float64Array(512);

            for(x=0; x<imgWidth; x++){
                for(y=0; y<imgHeight; y++){
                    var index = imgWidth * y + x;

                    var rgb = [data[index], data[index+1], data[index+2] ];

                    // put into relevant bank
                    var xbin = Math.floor((rgb[0]/255)*8)
                    var ybin = Math.floor((rgb[1]/255)*8)
                    var zbin = Math.floor((rgb[2]/255)*8)

                    histogram[ (ybin * 8 + xbin) * 8 + zbin ] ++;
                }
            }

            // normalize values.
            for(var i=0; i<512; i++) {
                histogram[i] /= totalPixels;
            }
```

This is how I am creating the histograms for the color palettes. The colors are just stored in an array of RGB values, each palette has 5 colors.

```
        var pals = [];

        palettes.forEach(function(palette){
            var paletteH = new Float64Array(512);
            palette.forEach(function(color){
                var xbin = Math.floor((color[0]/255)*8);
                var ybin = Math.floor((color[1]/255)*8);
                var zbin = Math.floor((color[2]/255)*8);
                paletteH[ (ybin * 8 + xbin) * 8 + zbin ] ++;
            });
            for(var i=0; i<512; i++) { paletteH[i] /= 5; }
            pals.push(paletteH);
        });
```

To calculate the chi-squared distance I'm looping through each palette getting the distance to the image histogram. Then the smallest should be most similar.

```
            for(var p = 0; p<pals.length; p++){
                var result = 0;
                for(var i=0; a = histogram[i], b = pals[p][i], i < 512; i++ ){
                    result += 0.5 * ( Math.pow(a-b,2) / (a + b + 1e-10));
                }
                console.log(result);
            }
```

This works, but the results seem wrong. For example I'll analyse an image of a forest scene expecting it to result in the green color palette, but it will return another. I'd appreciate any guidance at all.

Comment: You might find working with histograms more effective.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a least squares difference between your palette color and sample color.

Also you need to do this for each channel R G B and possibly A.

It would look something like this (pseudo code in [...]):

```
var min = 999999;
var paletteMatch;

[loop sample colors] {
  [loop palette colors] {

    float lsd = (Math.pow(paletteR - sampleR, 2) + [greed] + [blue]) / 3;

    if (lsd < min) {
      min = lsd;
      paletteMatch = currentPaletteInThisLoop;
    }
  }
  [award a point for paletteMatch for this sample Color
}

[which palette has the most points?]
```